# What does "--dryrun" do in Robot Framework pybot command?

Tags: robotframework

I have used `--dryrun` along with my pybot command; I want to know what exactly it validates for in testcase or in library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It parses all of the test suites and executes the tests. It does not execute any keywords, but it does parse them for correctness. The main benefits listed by the user guide are:

- Using keywords that are not found.
- Using keywords with wrong number of arguments.
- Using user keywords that have invalid syntax.
- In addition to these failures, normal execution errors are shown, for example, when test library or resource file imports cannot be resolved.

For more information see http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dry-run